# wampp does not recognize php script on windows 8

Tags: php, apache

I have installed wammp on windows 8. a simple test `echo 'test';` doesn't show 'test'.
When I look at the "show source" of the browser, it shows `echo 'test';` which indicates that apache doesn't process the php code.

What is happening here and has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: You need to show us your code. Be sure you have your php tags in place, the appropriate file extension, and that you're accessing the file through the live wamp directory, and not directly. I've been running WAMPServer on Windows 8 for 9 months without issue.

Comment: It shouldn't be a Windows 8 problem, might be you need to configure your WAMPP server, may be you are using short tags and short tags are not enabled in php.ini??

Answer (score 1):

If I guess right and you wrote really just `echo 'test';` into your PHP file than you need to add the PHP tags:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```